# How to finalize the value_counts

Tags: pandas

I've tried value counts in my data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TYPE':['BOY','GIRL','GIRL','GIRL','BOY','GIRL','BOY'],'GROUP':['A','D','F','D','C','C','E']})
```

My result ought to be this

```
TYPE  A B C D E F
BOY   1 0 1 0 1 0
GIRL  0 0 1 2 0 1
TOTAL 1 0 2 2 1 1
```

What I was able to get

```
A    1
E    1
F    1
C    2
D    2
```

from my code

```
a = df.GROUP.value_counts(sort=False,ascending=False)

print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to get the frequencies, and slash off the Total column (since you're not interested in that):

```
columns = ["A","B","C","D","E", "F"]

res = (pd.crosstab(df.TYPE, df.GROUP, margins=True, margins_name='Total')
      .iloc[:,:-1]
      .reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)
      .rename_axis(None)

         )
 print(res)


GROUP   A   B   C   D   E   F
BOY     1   0   1   0   1   0
GIRL    0   0   1   2   0   1
Total   1   0   2   2   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It works well but not as what I wanted exactly.

Comment: what's missing?

Comment: TYPE appears below GROUP. Can the type be excluded in a way?

Comment: ```rename_axis``` can take care of that. check updated code.

Comment: Be blessed a lot this Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

groupby and unstack

```
df1 = df.groupby(['TYPE','GROUP'])['GROUP'].agg(len).unstack().fillna(0)
df1.loc['Total'] = df1.sum(axis=0)

GROUP   A   C   D   E   F
TYPE                    
BOY     1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
GIRL    0.0 1.0 2.0 0.0 1.0
Total   1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: Total column is not available?